# How to indicate what a boolean parameter for an Angular filter represents

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

If you look at something like this:
`{{data | customFilter:true}}` you won't know what that `true` stands for unless you look at the implementation of the filter.

Is there a more readable way of passing that argument, like `customerFilter:{showLabel:true}`?

Thanks.

Comment: You accidentally answered your own question. Write your filter expression like that and you'll get your _named_ object as a parameter in your filter: `app.filter('customFilter', function(){return function(data, params){var showLabel = params.showLabel;}})` ;)

Comment: Although in this case you found a nice solution, the problem you raise is somewhat inherent to many programming languages, except ones like Objective-C where function calls explicitly require declaring argument names as well as values.